# Can anybody tell me why is my react code not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a project on react. So, I didn't get too far(:-P).
Well my problem is that `ReactDOM.render()` is not rendering my elements. I am relatively new to React, so cannot debug it. Here is it:-

https://codepen.io/shreyas23-sk/pen/LxRgwL

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in the code

1. It's `React.Component`, not `React.component`
2. In the render-function of the Header component, you have a new line after `return` - Javascript automatically adds a semicolon here, you can prevent this with either writing the first JSX-line after the return, or you can wrap your return statement in parentheses

So either write:

```
return (
  <div>
  ...
)
```

or

```
return <div>
  ...
```